# Can I read a value using a path in OPC UA?

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

Consider this OPC UA tree (from a publicly available server at [`opc.tcp://opcuaserver.com:48010`](http://opcuaserver.com/)):

[image]

From what I understand, one can read values from the OPC UA server, using a Node ID (which uniquely identifies the node):

```js
const dataValue = await session.read({
  nodeId: "ns=3;s=AirConditioner_1.Temperature",
  attributeId: AttributeIds.Value
});
console.log(" Temperature = ", dataValue.toString());
```

Can I read the value programmatically by providing a path? If yes, how? Maybe it can be done in a few steps?

```js
const dataValue = await session.somehowReadTheValueFromPath(
  "Views.AirConditionerView.AirConditioner_1.Temperature.Value"
);
console.log(" Temperature = ", dataValue.toString());
```

I've seen some mentions of [`makeBrowsePath`](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/6efc1b90e4764d0d2c39a9c0ec03c3554b44d5c4/packages/node-opcua-service-translate-browse-path/source/make_browse_path.ts#L20) and [`translateBrowsePath`](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/6efc1b90e4764d0d2c39a9c0ec03c3554b44d5c4/packages/node-opcua-address-space/source/pseudo_session.ts#L259) but it's all new to me and I can't wrap my head around how these can be used.

Examples are using [node-opcua](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua) client. If you can provide advice in a language other than Node.js I'd appreciate that too!

Answer (score 1):

TranslateBrowsePathToNodeIds is *generally* used when programming against type definitions where you know what the path of BrowseNames will be because they are defined by the type definition of each node in the path.

You need to have an idea of the reference type between each BrowsePath component and the namespace index of the BrowseName of each component. There is no service to turn a generic looking path such as the one in your 2nd example into a NodeId.

Comment: Does it mean that it's possible for a parent to have 2 child nodes with the same name but in different namespaces? (in that case I'd see 2 visually identical nodes in the GUI, right?). I'd appreciate if you could update the answer with a scenario where path alone would be not enough to uniquely identify a node. Sorry OPC UA newbie here. Looking at the tree in the GUI it's not clear why it's not possible.

Comment: @MaxIvanov yes that is possible. That’s part of why namespaces exist - to disambiguate types and names that may otherwise look the same.